# arrangement name use LINQ for datatable

Tags: wpf, linq, sorting

I have a datatable

```
public void CreatTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("First Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Middle Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Last Name");
            dt.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C");
            dt.Rows.Add("A1", "B1", "C1");
            dt.Rows.Add("A2", "B2", "C2");
            dt.Rows.Add("A3", "B3", "C3");
            dt.Rows.Add("A4", "B4", "C3");
        }
```

I want to arrangement this table sorted by `Last Name > First Name > Middle Name` using `LINQ` and save to another table **(dt2)**. Looking for help, thanks

Comment: I'm learning for LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` extension methods.

```
var newTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Last Name"))
            .ThenBy(x=>x.Field<string>("First Name"))
            .ThenBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Middle Name"))
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1iCHoG)